# sentinel value and displaying my results

Tags: java

I've been trying to figure out my code for hours and I know this is probably something simple but I would really appreciate some help!

Here's my problem:

```
// Purpose: This program will prompt the user to enter a positive integer.
// The program will accept integers until the user enters a -1.
// Once the -1 is entered, the program will display the integers followed
// by their sum.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputSum
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

// variable declaration
int inputNumber;
int stringNumber = 0;
int num = 0;
int sum = 0;

// prompt user to enter an integer
System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
inputNumber = scan.nextInt();

// continue to have user enter integers until:
while (inputNumber >= 0)
{
sum += inputNumber;
stringNumber = inputNumber++;
System.out.print("\n Enter another positive integer (enter -1 to quit): ");
inputNumber = scan.nextInt();
// -1 is entered
if (inputNumber == -1)
{
break;
}
}
// display results
System.out.print("\n The integers you entered were: " + Integer.toString(stringNumber));
System.out.print("\n The sum of the intergers are: " + sum);



}
}
```

Right now my results are showing my sum correctly, but it's supposed to display the integers I enter in a line separated by commas. (EX: if the user enters 1, 1, 1 my results should be The integers you entered were: 1, 1, 1   The sum of the integers are: 3). And right now it's adding my integers entered to the sentinel value and displaying my results as: The integers you entered were: 1.

I'm really stuck on how to do this. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must store the input each time.

Replace

```
stringNumber = inputNumber++;
```

by

```
stringNumber += inputNumber+", ";
```

This will store the inputs in `inputNumber`.

Change

```
System.out.print("\n The integers you entered were: " + Integer.toString(stringNumber));
```

into

```
System.out.print("\n The integers you entered were: " + stringNumber);
```

This will display all inputs entered.

Answer (score 0):

You are only printing the last number you entered :

```
System.out.print("\n The integers you entered were: " + Integer.toString(stringNumber));
```

If you wish to print all the input numbers, you have to store them somewhere.

If you wish to store them in `stringNumber`, change its type to `StringBuilder`, and append each number to it.

```
StringBuilder stringNumber = new StringBuilder();
...
stringNumber.append(inputNumber);
stringNumber.append(", ");
...
System.out.print("\n The integers you entered were: " + stringNumber.toString());
```

You'll have to make a slight adjustment to this code, in order to avoid printing an extra "," after the last number.